# Tumblr share button not working

Tags: javascript, html, url, web-applications, tumblr

I'm trying to add a tumblr share button to my webshop and i don't get the Tumblr Share Button ([see here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/buttons)) to work.

- I want to share a **picture** of a product which is customized by the user, and set a **clickthrough link** to the product page.
- Since the shop is built on Knockout.js and the product configurator is loaded dynamically, the script "[share.js](http://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share.js)" provided by tumblr does not work.

So the URL my share button has looks like the following:

```
var url = 'http://www.tumblr.com/share/photo';
url += '?source=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.filltheblank.de/public/images/taschen/7_16.1-17.3-18.122-19.129-20.132_1.jpg');
url += '&caption=' + encodeURIComponent('little black dress bag');
url += '&click_thru=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.filltheblank.de/konfigurator/#step:1|product:7_16.1-17.3-18.122-19.129-20.132');
```

Or if you put it together:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/share/photo?source=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.filltheblank.de%2Fpublic%2Fimages%2Ftaschen%2F7_16.1-17.3-18.122-19.129-20.132_1.jpg&caption=little%20black%20dress%20bag&click_thru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.filltheblank.de%2Fkonfigurator%2F%23step%3A1%7Cproduct%3A7_16.1-17.3-18.122-19.129-20.132
```

When you open that link, the sharer will appear just fine. 
But if you click "Create post", the page will redirect you to a page where you can share the sharing page itself... And not post anything!

I also tried using another URL scheme, provided by tumblr (but not documented):

```
http://www.tumblr.com/share?v=3&u=[url]&t=[title]&s=
```

This does work, but does not support including a picture or setting a click through link. Combining both methods also does not work.

So does anybody know what i can do to get it to work?
I would also be very thankful if someone could answer me one of these questions:

- does the script "share.js" provided by tumblr do anything important other than making a popup-link out of my ordinary link?
- Could it be a problem that i rewrite the URL of the product page with javascript dynamically?

Any help would be much appreciated as i'm stuck here and i feel like i tried everything.

Comment: Include the code for your question in the question.  Don't rely on external links, since they may change, making your question useless.  StackOverflow is a library, a collection of questions to be used as a reference, not just a discussion forum.

Comment: Please don't downvote. It's not in the Javascript code. My problem is in the URL, or the GET Parameters. I had the URL in my post directly but it was edited out by someone.

Comment: I edited the question some more to provide some more info on what i want to do and what i tried so far. I'm still stuck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image path you are using (param value for "source") is not an image.  It is in fact a 301 (redirect) to an HTML page.  Can you try using an image path that has the appropriate content type?

Comment: Oops, the image path was outdated, i changed some stuff in the system since i posted the question. I edited my post!

Comment: I tried it again and now it is working! The only explanation is that before i tried to share a transparent png and now i share a jpg.

Comment: It seems that beginning 2018 (at least) the “/share/photo?source=…” does no longer work. Share buttons take the information of pages og: instead. It definitely worked before for me and stopped working now. I tried also with .jpg image instead of .png. Same result.